# get the count value in stdClass object with foreach loops

Tags: php, arrays

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [count] => 3  ) ) 
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [count] => 1 ) ) 
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [count] => 2 ) )
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [count] => 0 ) )
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [count] => 0 )  ) 
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [count] => 0 )  )
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [count] => 0 )  )
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [count] => 3 )  )
```

i want to print only 3 1 2 0 0 0 0 3

Comment: That's great for you! congratulations :)

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach($data as $array)
{
   echo $array[0]->count;
}
```